# auto inject code to web's html

Tags: html

When watching video on coursera, I think that the subtitle size is too large. After google this problem, I find a solution:

```
video::-webkit-media-text-track-display {
    font-size: 30%;
}
```

inject the code above to the position shown below.

[image]

However, I need to inject the code manually every time opening a new coursera video webpage.
Is there anyway to auto inject the code when I watching coursera video?
Please show me the solution step by step. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you’re only changing the CSS. You can use the Stylebot plugin:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Search on Google `customize css of a site chrome plugin` then install one of those plugin and follow instruction.